# C++, аргументы по умолчанию в параметрах шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, аргументы

Я изучаю книгу по программированию шаблонов `C++` и встретил абзац, который вызвал у меня ряд вопросов, четкого ответа на которые я нигде не нашел.

Абзац касается аргументов по умолчанию в параметрах шаблона:

```
В принципе можно иметь аргументы по умолчанию для ведущих параметров шаблона 
функции, даже если за ними следуют параметры без аргументов по умолчанию:

template<typename RT = long, typename Tl, typename T2>
RT max(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

Я всегда считал, что аргументы по умолчанию должны идти в конце списка аргументов. Это и логично, потому что если они будут идти не в конце, тогда возникает неопределенность.

Мои вопросы заключаются в следующем:

1. Почему возможно исключение из этого правила?
2. Только ли для шаблонов это позволено?

Comment: Кстати, тэг "шаблоны" относится к шаблонам проектирования; для вашего вопроса нужен тэг "шаблоны-с++". Ну, я уже исправил :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это несколько разные правила. Здесь `T1` и `T2` *выводятся* из переданных аргументов.
Например:

```
auto L = max(1,'c');
```

Ясно, что `T1=int`, `T2=char`, а не указанный тип `L` - и есть `long`.

А вот если написать

```
auto L = max<double>(1,'c');
```

то тем самым указываем, что `RT` - `double`. А тут

```
auto L = max<double,int,int>(1,'c');
```

указаны явно (а не выводятся) и остальные типы.

Дело еще и в том, что при указании параметров типа вы должны указывать их по очереди, включая параметр по умолчанию. Например,

```
template<typename RT = long, typename T1, typename T2>
RT vax(T1 a)
{
    T2 b = 0;
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

и вызов

```
auto s = vax<double,int>(2);
```

означают, что у вас `RT` - `double`, `T1` - `int`, а не `T1` - `double`, `T2` - `int`, а `RT` - `long`, так что никакой неоднозначности тут нет... А код не скомпилируется, пока вы не укажете явно *все три* типа.

В случае обычных функций параметры без значений по умолчанию опущены быть не могут, в то время как в шаблоне - они могут быть выведены.

Answer (score 6):

Это позволено только для шаблонов функций (не классов).

Это становится возможном, потому что в точке вызова функции типы T1 и T2 могут быть выведены из типов арнументов функции. Т.е. в виде псевдокода:

```
template< typename RT = long, typename Tl=decltype(a), typename T2=decltype(b) >
RT max(auto a, auto b)
{
    return b < a ? a : b;
}
```

В случае частичной специализации, такой псевдокод не написать, но принцип доступности информации о типах на основании аргментов функции - сохраняется.